# Is it worth it to do "manual" caching in Symfony 4/Doctrine 2?

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have these two tables

`items`

- id
- name

`itemStats` (many to one relation to `items` table)

- id
- item_id
- update_time
- stat_value

In most pages, the application will just display a summary of items in list forms and will need to query the most recent `update_time` and min/max values of `stat_value`

Currently it's setup to just do the full query each time it's needed but since the data is written once a day only and read maybe thousands of times per day is it worth caching it in the `items` table? (by adding `lastUpdate`, `minStat',`maxStat`fields that would be updated after each INSERT in the`itemStats` table)

Or is Symfony or Doctrine doing enough caching behind the scenes on all frequent queries to make it useless do to any on our own?

Comment: How many thousands of times per day is it read? You may be trying to optimize something that does not really need to be optimized because the performance gain would be negligible at best.

Comment: That's still an unknown but I'd rather be ready for the worst case. Especially if the "manual caching" operation can be offloaded during off hours where nobody is using the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Symfony nor Doctrine should/could do any caching, since they cannot know when data might have changed and the cache has to be invalidated.

So add the extra fields if you can keep them up to date easily.

Or check the caching-options of your database of choice and let the DBMS do all the work:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(update_time) as lastUpdateTime,
  MIN(stat_value) as minStat,
  MAX(stat_value) as maxStat
FROM
  itemStats
GROUP BY
  item_id
```

**MariaDB Query Cache**: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/query-cache/